# Any recent textbooks for an "Introduction to Databases" course?

Tags: undergraduate, databases

Are you aware of any recently published textbooks (2018-2022) suitable for an introductory course in databases? I've been using the classical textbooks so far, i.e. "Database Systems Complete Book", "Fundamentals of Database Systems", "Database System Concepts". Would like to hear from you of any new entries, preferably with additional materials for instructors. Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect that a new book would add of value that a classic book is missing? I ask because for an introductory course I would not expect there to be a need beyond using a classic book.

Comment: @GuyCoder possibly new exercises, quizzes, online resources, slides, NoSQL new technologies, etc.

Comment: I don't plan to write an answer. IMHO in your list the only item that can not be found in a classic book is the NoSQL and new technologies. See: [Neo4j books](https://neo4j.com/books/). Learning Neo4j help me understand the pitfalls of SQL that are not typically advertised. That is not saying SQL should not be used but that for certain problems SQL is the wrong tool.

Comment: I'd look at books (like)  [Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel](https://www.amazon.com/dp/111902143X/ref=cm_sw_r_awdo_navT_g_2VXHEBVGVSMKPE13V3R2). (Disclaimer I've not seen it myself. Just that the direction seems good)

Comment: @Rusi thank you! That book does not seem to cover the theory of relational database design, i.e. normal forms, functional dependencies, etc.

Comment: I guess not... But if you want "current-spiciness" plus stable timeless theory it's likely hard to find in one single place. Put differently the difference between a modest and a stellar course is likely that the first sticks to one text whereas the second mixes and matches material to teacher's taste/student possibilities. However **WARNING** : Too many a struggling teacher has moved from modest to disaster by over reaching their capabilities! (And I'm chary of the nosql fad)

Comment: @GuyCoder Just about everything the original Neo4j book said about relational DBs was wrong so I wouldn't trust anything about the relational model written from a Neo4j source.